# Expectation value of $e^{\frac{i f(t)}{2} \sigma^z_1 \sigma^z_2 }$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observables

What should be an intuitive way to start thinking when I need to compute the expectation value of  $e^{\frac{i f(t)}{2} \sigma^z_1 \sigma^z_2 }$? Do I need to expand it into a series and truncate first?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/608226/expression-involving-pauli-spin-matrices/608263#608263). Not exactly the same exponential, but you can use the same method.

Comment: BTW, in the usual basis, $\sigma^{z}_1 \otimes \sigma^{z}_2$ is a diagonal matrix, so you can just exponentiate term by term.

Comment: @secavara, by 'term by tern' did you mean each element at a time in the matrix?

Comment: @secavara, also, the paper referred to in the question you have linked uses the term 'fundamental interval' for $\tau$. Could you please define 'fundamental interval'?

Comment: Yes, I mean each element in the matrix. I have not read the paper, for the purpose of the question it didn't really matter what $\tau$ was, as long as it was a number and not an operator.

Answer (score 0):

My intuition is usually to find the eigenstates of the operator, express the state in terms of that eigenbasis, then take the appropriate linear combination of the eigenvalues weighted by the probabilities of the state in the eigenbasis.

This leads to another question: is there an intuitive way to find the eigenvalues and eigenstates of this operator? Yes! Any state $|\psi\rangle$ that is a joint eigenstate of both $\sigma_1^z$ and $\sigma_2^z$, satisfying some equations $\sigma_i^z|\psi\rangle=\lambda^{(i)}|\psi\rangle$ will be an eigenstate of your operator, with eigenvalue $e^{\frac{i f(t)}{2}\lambda^{(1)}\lambda^{(2)}}$. So if we label these eigenstates by their eigenvalues, where $\sigma_1^z\otimes \sigma_2^z|\lambda^{(1)}_i,\lambda^{(2)}_i\rangle=\lambda^{(1)}_i \lambda^{(2)}_i|\lambda^{(1)}_i,\lambda^{(2)}_i\rangle$, then the expectation value of your operator in the state $$|\Psi\rangle=\sum_i \psi_i |\lambda^{(1)}_i,\lambda^{(2)}_i\rangle$$ will be
$$\langle\Psi|e^{\frac{if(t)}{2}\sigma_1^z\otimes\sigma_2^z}|\Psi\rangle=\sum_i |\psi_i|^2e^{\frac{i f(t)}{2}\lambda^{(1)}_i\lambda^{(2)}_i}.$$

How do we justify the above? We expand our operator using the definition of an exponential:
$$e^{A}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{n!}.$$ When acting on an eigenstate $|a\rangle$, we obtain the desired eigenvalue equation
$$e^{A}|a\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{n!}|a\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!}|a\rangle=e^a|a\rangle.$$